# How do I exit a stuck/frozen post mission menu in Warframe?

Tags: warframe

I've just completed my mission and opened the menu by clicking the menu button in the corner too soon, but now I'm stuck in my ship, unable to move or even open the menu.

This has happened several times now and seems to be tied to clicking the menu button before the post-mission results screen closes.

What can I do to get around this?

Comment: https://forums.warframe.com/topic/933623-ui-hidden-after-clicking-menu-before-post-mission-results-close/ bug report I posted

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to close another screen, like your Armory or Foundry, but you can't access it because the menu button and ESC buttons don't work. A trick I found is viewing a userprofile via chat:

```
/profile TankorSmash (or your own username)
```

and then immediately close it, and the UI will work as intended, and WASD will let you move around.

Comment: This happens on PS4 too (I'm not sure what triggers it), with the difference being that you can access your menus (`Options` button). I've found that by repeatedly teleporting myself around the ship by, like you say, visiting the Armory or Foundry, etc., eventually I'll become unfrozen.